# SQL Server 2005 Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, view

I have a table that contains multiple records per employee by effective data and effective sequence: EMPLID, EFFDT, EFFSEQ.

I am trying to come up with a view in which I could specify an As Of Date other than the current date and get the most current record for each employee as of that date.  The query that I usually use is:

```
SELECT C.EMPLID, C.EFFDT, C.EFFSEQ
  FROM PS_JOB C
 WHERE C.EFFSEQ = (SELECT MAX(INNERALIAS.EFFSEQ)
                     FROM PS_JOB INNERALIAS 
                    WHERE INNERALIAS.EMPLID = C.EMPLID
                      AND INNERALIAS.EFFDT = C.EFFDT)
   AND C.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(INNERALIAS.EFFDT)
                    FROM PS_JOB INNERALIAS 
                   WHERE INNERALIAS.EMPLID = C.EMPLID
                     AND INNERALIAS.EFFDT <= GetDate())
```

Is there any way to create a view on SQL Server in which I can specify a date to compare the `INNERALIAS.EFFDT` to in the second subselect?

Comment: You seem to be looking for a parameterized view. That's known as a table-valued function.

Comment: Is there a reason you want a view instead of a stored proc or @table function?

Comment: Yes.  I am able to create a sp and/or a function, but my challenge is to create an Excel-based report using this information.  When I try to include a subselect in my Excel reports, they GUI can no longer be used for edits (parameters, modification, etc.).  I'm trying to create a view (or some other means) to get around it.

Comment: It sounds like Excel may not work for you.  Depending on what edition of SQL Server you are using, you may want to explore SQL Server Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize a view, but you can leave your view as is and parameterize a sp that returns results from the view limited by your parameter and send the output of the sp to a table and use that table in Excel.

Comment: Is there anyway to have the user Execute the sp via Excel (or some other user friendly means)?

Comment: I think you'll need more than Excel for that.  Maybe an Access front end?